# Enable recognition continuous speech

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

How to enable the recognition of continuous speech using the **REST API** (with javascript SDK) **Bing Speech API**?

Using the example do Javascript SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-JavaScript can only transcribe short sentences with the microphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to Microsoft about this and was told that the code in Javascript  for their SDK doesn't allow continuous speech yet.

Comment: Does the .net web version supports it?

Answer (score 1):

The preview version of Microsoft.Cogntitive.Speech API supports recognizing continuous speech.

Check it out here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text-sample

Currently, it does not support Javascript. It supports C++/C#/Java.